# What format is person's ImageData(CFDataRef) in AddressBook?(Jpeg or PNG)?Or how to determine?

Tags: image, png, jpeg, nsdata, addressbook

From AddressBook's API `ABPersonCopyImageData` I can get a CFDateRef which is toll-free bridge to NSData. And I want to write this data to file, but what file extension should I use ?
.jpeg or .png?

The documentation doesn't mention what the data is.Is there any way to know?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData  *imgData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        if (!img) {
            img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage.png"];
        }
```